# Table of arraylists

Tags: arraylist, null, fill, dimensions

I'm trying to fill a sort of table of arraylists.

The idea I'm tried doing is a two dimensional arraylist:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> mainAutresHauteValeur = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

except that in one dimension I always have N values
I tried initializing by adding null N times in one dimension but then I have a null pointer exception when I want to add an integer to the arraylist number I  (0<=i<=N)
I also tried creating an arraylist and adding it N times to initialize it but then all the arraylists number I stay equal.

The idea I'm trying to conceive is a merging between a table in one direction and an arraylist in the other direction

Comment: I can't figure out which language your question refers to – I'm guessing C++? In any case, please add a tag for that, so people proficient in that language can find your question.

Answer (score 0):

> i also tried creating an arraylist and adding it N times to initialize it but then all the arraylists number i stay equal...

Just add N different array lists instead of the same one; for instance, with something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    mainAutresHauteValeur.Add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
}
```

(Note that the above is pseudo-code; adapt as necessary for your language/libraries of choice.)